# Convert a date with string format to timestap in a loop

Tags: python, pandas, date, timestamp

I have a dict with dates, some are timestamps, some date as string.
I would like to iterate over a dict. If the val is as sting, convert it to a timestamp. If not only print it.

```
import pandas as pd
ts = pd.Timestamp('2017-01-01T12')
date = '2017-01-01'

timedict = {
  "timestamp": ts,
  "date": date
}

for key, val in timedict.items():
    if val == #string:
        val.strftime('%d.%m.%Y')
        print(val)
        
    else:
        print(val)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

Using [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) to parse and format the string

```py
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd

ts = pd.Timestamp("2017-01-01T12")
date = "2017-01-01"

timedict = {
    "timestamp": ts,
    "date": date,
}

for key, val in timedict.items():
    if isinstance(val, str):
        val = datetime.strptime(val, "%Y-%m-%d")
        val = val.strftime("%d.%m.%Y")
        print(val)
    else:
        print(val)
```

Which outputs:

```
2017-01-01 12:00:00
01.01.2017
```

---

Or, as you're already using pandas you can create a `pd.Timestamp` from the parsed `datetime` object:

```py
for key, val in timedict.items():
    if isinstance(val, str):
        val = pd.Timestamp(datetime.strptime(val, "%Y-%m-%d"))
        print(val)
    else:
        print(val)
```

Comment: thank you, i can work with your solution!!